# How to share Windows7's XAMPP installation with Windows XP running on vmWare Player

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vmware, xampp

In order to check my web in IE 7, I am running Windows7 and also Windows XP under vmWare Player within Windows7.

My internet connection in vmWare is shared from the host as 'NAT' and able to see internet.

I am using XAMPP on Windows7 for developing sites. I use http://localhost/mysite to open the site under development in Windows7.

I wanted to use http://localhost/mysite to open in the Windows XP under vmWare as well.

When I browse http://localhost/mysite in IE7 in XP, I get 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'.

Kindly help me with the process of how to access these sites in vmWare.

Thanks in advance.

The topic is similar to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862118/how-to-share-ubuntus-xampp-installation-with-windows-7-running-on-vmware-worksta
But it did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hitting the IP address of the XAMPP server directly instead of `localhost`. Ex. http://192.168.0.100/mysite.  Or try using the actual hostname of your Win7 computer - ex. http://win7/mysite.  If that doesn't work (no name resolution) you can add an entry to your hosts file on your WinXP box that has the correct IP and hostname of your Win7 box in order to access it by name.

Also, you might want to make sure that your Win7 box's firewall isn't blocking port 80 (or whatever port you use for webdev).

Comment: What do I need to add my hosts file on your WinXP ? I added port 80 to Win7 firewall, but it still does not show. I tried 127.0.0.1 but did not work either.

Comment: You need to put the IP of the Win7 box. Not 127.0.0.1 (that's the loopback address), but rather its actual NIC address - likely a 192.168.x.x address. But try just hitting it by IP first - only edit the hosts file once its working by IP.

Comment: I used 192.168.1.2 and it works. Thanks.